# Facebook Facepile Batch Requests

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have multiple facepile plugins on one page.  When each one loads, another request is issued.  Is there a way to batch the requests of all the plugins on one page?

An alternative solution would be to create my own version of the plugin.  How would I achieve the same functionality with my own code?

Answer (score 0):

Not as I know, so far. You can build the facetile contents by building a batch request which will provide yiou the needed data.